# ajax passing along multiple vars, one which is an array, how to pass and read the array?

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

Environment: PHP 5.3.5 MySQL Server 5.5.8

I have 3 variables to send to php via an ajax call. one of which might be an array if a user selects one or more values from a select list.

I can view the values in an alert in jQuery before I make the ajax call to php.

I cannot seem to review the values on the php side, there is an error and I am getting back "No Contacts Inserted", so the insert is failing.

Here is the output I receive beofre the ajax function is called:

```
handler= setStActivitySharing, stu_id=31, user_ids=3,5
```

I believe how I am wrapping my data and sending it to the php is incorrect.

Here is the javascript, which calls the ajax:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e)
      {


       var selectedOptions = $("#stActivityShareList").val();
       var handler = $("#handler").val();
       var stu_id = $("#stu_id").val();             
      //   $("#output").html("<b>You are sharing this file with: </b>" + selectedOptions);

       insertContactsForActivitySharing(handler, stu_id, selectedOptions);
 });

 function insertContactsForActivitySharing(handler, stu_id, selectedOptions)
{

  alert("handler="+handler +", stu_id="+ stu_id + ", selectOptions="+ selectedOptions);

  //IS THIS CORRECT?!?!?!?!
  var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
      handler: handler,
      stu_id: stu_id,
      selectedOptions:selectedOptions
  });

   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "models/ajaxHandler.php",
            data: dataObject,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(result){


                if (result !== null)
                {
                    alert(result);
                    //$("#output").html(result);
                    HideDialog(false);
                    e.preventDefault();              
                }

            },
            error: function(){
                alert("ajax failure: could not share activity the selected persons");
            }
       });
}
```

AjaxHandler.php is as follows....

```
if(isset($_POST['handler']))
{
    $handler = $_POST['handler'];
    if (!empty($handler)){
        echo $handler;
       // processHandler($handler);
    }else{
        echo "Unable to complete the request: " + $handler+". ";
    }
}
```

Even just trying to echo the handler stops the whole process. I want to be able to confirm that the three vars I am passing along in ajax are making it to the php, but I take it there is something amiss here. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the var dataObject, and assigned the data in the ajax call to be as follows:

"handler="+handler+"&stu_id="+stu_id+"&selectedOptions="+selectedOptions

It's a step backwards but I won't complain cause it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

While your form method is post, you are passing handler as a get var. You can change your php to check for `$_GET['handler']`

```
if(isset($_GET['handler']))
{
    do_alert("form handler");
    $handler = $_GET['handler'];
    if (!empty($handler)){
        processHandler($handler);
    }else{
        echo "Unable to complete the request: " + $handler+". ";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a hidden input field to the form which will send as a post var:

```
<input type="hidden" name="handler" value="share" />
```

By the way, your `#btnSubmit` listener is probably not doing anything because your submit button is submitting the form. You're not likely to see the message that listener is trying to deliver. You should instead pass that message after PHP processes the form or submit the form via ajax and have that message prompt in a success callback.

Comment: So remove the var because that is for GET. Got it. For Post I need to use the hidden way.

 I tried to remove it and still no success in reaching that first javascript alert.

Comment: No, you can use both `get` and `post` at the same time if you really want to. I'm just saying your PHP has to match the values the form is sending, post OR get. Get is anything passed in the URL. Post is passed as fields in the form when the form method is set to post. Somehow I think you're confusing the two or not fully understanding how they work. Feel free to ask and I can clarify so long as I understand the request

Comment: That makes sense I thought the form was limited to the method that was listed. Do I have to modify the method if using both?

Comment: No, the basic idea is to understand that $_GET is available no matter what the method of the form is. You can still POST to a URL that has $_GET parameters and use those $_GET vars in conjunction with your $_POST vars if you are so inclined. In your case we don't know how critical $_GET['handler'] is to anything else on the page so I can't tell you to just remove it. If handler is not used for anything besides this form, then it makes more sense to add it as a hidden field and switch your form method to post. In other words, if you have no reason to mix GET and POST then avoid it.

Comment: I have removed said fields nd have created them as hidden ones. Now they look like this:                <input name="stu_id"  type="hidden" value=[activity.st_usage_id] />               <input name="handler"  type="hidden"  value="setStActivitySharing" />                     still not working. Sorry for the ws.

Comment: Can you access that page directly? seeing a url like /models/formHandler.php makes me wonder if there's some kind of framework or other routing system that prevents direct access to models.

Comment: Okay so weekend's over. Yes I can access that page. if I type in the full string using localhost.  *Commences to beat head against desk* I can see the alert just staring at me and laughing.

Comment: The modal window (dialog box) is being displayed after a success call return from ajax has been completed. Is it this that is preventing it from connecting to the PHP?

Comment: Is this whole form in a modal box? If so, why not just use jquery ajax to submit the form and update the modal window with the results?

Comment: Yeah I sat back and recently discovered the same thing. Sorry I am still new to this and I thought I'd give the form method a try. Once I realized that the form redirects the page I thought no. This is not what I want. So I am attempting the ajax method as we speak.

Comment: I updated my question above to reflect the new issue I am encountering. I just want to resolve this and move on. :)